# Plot function without isolating

Tags: math, plot, wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to plot a function in Mathematica without isolating y first?

Something like this:

```
Plot[2*x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}]
```

Comment: Would it be cheating to use `Solve` ?

Comment: What do you want to use Solve for?

Answer (score 1):

```
ContourPlot[2*x + y == 2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}]
```

https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot.html

Comment: CountorPlot gives a weird graph :(

Comment: @WYS What graph are you expecting?  `CountourPlot` is the canonical answer for this problem.  If you want something else you'll have to make clear what it is.